# How to use the minimum latency in Amazon EC2 around the globe?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

We have few websites that are going to store and serve up a decent amount of data and MySQL queries in EC2 to a global audience where latency should be minimized.

I am currently in Europe, so the websites latency are around 80ms, as the instance region is in Europe/Ireland.

But when I load the website from USA, the latency increases to 300ms, I wonder, how we can set up a system in Amazon that will load the website with the fastest way possible but around the world? I am not talking about images or files, I am talking about a complete website.

Thanks

Comment: CloudFront, milti-region, its a large topic and not really sutible for here

Comment: I just couldn't find a step by step guide yet, Should I create instances for each region, and pay for each one then link them together using routing 53? or how exactly, any info or links will be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

A few rules of thumb:

- Keep your **database** as close as possible to your application (same region)
- **Offload** as much as possible from your application/web servers by serving static data via Amazon S3 and/or Amazon CloudFront (eg images, style sheets, javascript includes)
- If speed is critical, **cache data** where possible to reduce database queries (eg use ElasticCache, or similar, in front of a database)

Most of the time taken to render a web page isn't the response time to receive the HTML page from the web server, it's normally the additional files used to populate the page, such as images, style sheets and scripts.

Therefore, you could then run the application out of one region. Speeding up the other content through CloudFront will provide a much faster experience for the user, since that content will be served closer to the user.

Once you have that operational, spend some time measuring what is taking time to serve the website. Identify what is taking the longest time, then concentrate on reducing that element.

This will be much easier than going multi-region immediately, which would involve a lot of technical overhead for possibly little gain.

Comment: Thanks for your response, we already have S3 setup, and database in the same region, the website doesn't have any issues regarding speed.
Basically, from EU, the TTFB speed is 80ms, if I open the site from the USA, it becomes 300ms, I read this is because of the region latency, (the far you go, the more latency you'll get). If I want to implement this feature, should I pay more, and should I create an instance in each region and then somehow link them?

Comment: If they need to share data, then you would need a way to replicate data between all regions. This would depend on how you store your data. Which database do you use? With DynamoDB it is easier. Does 80ms vs 300ms really matter to your end users? What is the _total_ page load time? It would be more than that.

Comment: No, I use my own MySQL server. that is installed in the instance.

It does matter, not because of page load, ajax requests take 400 ms total on US end, and from EU, it takes 110 ms, I sell PHP scripts online, so the speed is very important for customers.

Is there any docs or guide I can follow to reach this? 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Amazon `Route 53` and `EC2`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/TutorialAddingLBRRegion.html

Comment: link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Not clear mate.

Should I create instances for each region?

Comment: Yeah that's the idea, AWS should handle the load balancing for you.

Comment: So basically I should pay for 4 regions to get this done? or load balancer covers the cost of the 4 instances?